# github on server - Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:

Tags: php, git, github, composer-php, server

i deploy using laravel forge from a github repo.
this repo worked until i made some change to a few views did a composer update, and it grabbed some new symfony components and removed a social media generator i no longer used.

now, on forge, after deploying to github, i get this:

```
From github.com:jeffwalsh/wittischism
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
vendor/autoload.php
vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php
vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php
vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php
vendor/composer/autoload_real.php
vendor/composer/installed.json
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
Updating 0d5c6df..dbadbdb
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
```

the site still works but nothing from the last commit is active.

all the changes in the github commit show they all relate to composer.
i've tried all the solutions posted so far on github, but most pertain to this error occuring in a different circumstance.

i've tried stash, merge, stash pop, i've tried resetting headers, etc. if i try another commit it says i am up to date.

i've also tried git add file/name/here.php and then commit but it says im up to date. also tried git add -a and the same thing.

Comment: This is for deployment? You probably want to `git reset --hard HEAD`.